# Should i use device-width or a fixed width for my viewport

Tags: mobile, web, mobile-website

When creating a mobile optimized web page, im trying to figure out the pros and cons of using device-width vs. fixed width in the viewport meta tag.

**Fixed width:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640" />
```

**Device width**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

What is the benefits of using device-width over a fixed width? Because to me the solution of creating a 640px wide webpage with a 640px wide viewport is the simplest to create a page that always fills the entire width of the screen not matter the actual width/height specs of the phone.

I can maybe see some problems when using fixed width if i want to support both landscape / portait? Or maybe it has something to do with your cant use media queries for targetting because it will always asume the fixed width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this viewport:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

I had problems with scaling when I change the orientation of the device, but with this, whatever the orientation (horizontal/vertical) the mobile website fits the phone screen perfectly.

Comment: What is the difference between initial-scale=1 and device-width?

Comment: I'd think it should have the same function, and it has, but for some reason iPhone when used in horizontal orientation doesn't respect the "width=device-width" and page becomes around 25% wider than the device. The viewport that I suggested works fine.

Comment: Great, but when real question is really why not use a fixed width layout, and thereby have alot more styling control, because you know the excatly how many pixels you have in the width, instead of taking the device-width approach which requires you to create a fluid layout?

Comment: How do you know exactly the width when each device is different? Blackberry is wider than iPhone, and Android can be wider as well. And how about tablet? And also the horizontal view is wider than vertical.

Comment: As i understand when setting the viewport width to 640px on a 640px wide webpage it will fill the entire width of any device? thereby i know in my styling that 640px = 100%. I guess 640 could be any number.

Comment: If you set your website to 640px it'll either overflow the device width and part of the page will not be visible, or it will zoom out to fit the whole 640px on the screen and your page will be unreadable, and will have to be scrolled and zoomed by the user.

Comment: Your right 640 is a too large number and should instead something in the 320 range and then it will just scale up on larger displays. I can see a problem if you limit your viewport to 320 in width when viewing the page in landscape, because you could take advandtage of more space. But thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: I think you have to specify as width=640 and not width=640px also

Comment: Safer to use width, not device-width. https://www.sitepoint.com/media-queries-width-vs-device-width/#:~:text=However%20the%20main%20difference%20between,device%20pixels%20per%20CSS%20pixel.